# problem of alternating between two handler event functions

Tags: javascript, redux, javascript-objects

i had a game react matching card project to do.the game is consist to choose card in card grid if two carts contents is the same so this two cart will be her matched property true and will be displaying in green color and in the score component will mark 2 matched cards and so on if the card is not matched the cards color contents will be in red and another handler function will come here to make the two cards invisible by change the property of card object visible to false I had release this function it work well in the console but when I try it in the code application it not work at all please help me to fix it there is my code components :

```
the boardSlice: 
const initialState = [
  {id: 0, contents: 'Provider', visible: true, matched: true}, 
  {id: 1, contents: 'Provider', visible: true, matched: true}, 
  {id: 2, contents: 'selector', visible: true, matched: true}, 
  {id: 3, contents: 'selector', visible: true, matched: true}, 
  {id: 4, contents: 'useSelector()', visible: true, matched: true}, 
  {id: 5, contents: 'useSelector()', visible: true, matched: true}, 
  {id: 6, contents: 'useDispatch()', visible: true, matched: true}, 
  {id: 7, contents: 'useDispatch()', visible: true, matched: true}, 
  {id: 8, contents: 'Pure Function', visible: true, matched: true}, 
  {id: 9, contents: 'Pure Function', visible: true, matched: true}, 
  {id: 10, contents: 'react-redux', visible: true, matched: true}, 
  {id: 11, contents: 'react-redux', visible: true, matched: true}, 
];

export const boardReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'board/setBoard':
      let setState = [];
      action.payload.forEach((element, index) => 
        setState.push({id: index, 
                      contents: element, 
                      visible: false, 
                      matched: false})
      );
      return setState;
         
    case 'board/flipCard':
      let flipState = [...state];
      const cardID = action.payload;
      flipState[cardID] = {...state[cardID], visible:true}
      const [index1, index2] = flipState.filter(card => card.visible).map(card => card.id);
      if (index2 !== undefined) {
        let card1 = flipState[index1];
        let card2 = flipState[index2];
        if (card1.contents === card2.contents) {
          flipState[index1] = {...card1, visible: false, matched: true};
          flipState[index2] = {...card2, visible: false, matched: true};
        }
      }
    return flipState;
 case 'board/resetUnmatchedCards':
  let newState = [...state];
  let [indexa, indexb] = newState.filter(card => card.visible === true && card.matched === false).map(card => card.id);
  if (indexb !== undefined) {
    let cardA = newState[indexa];
    let cardB = newState[indexb];
    newState[indexa] = {...cardA, visible: action.payload};
    newState[indexb] = {...cardB, visible: action.payload}
  }
  return newState
    case 'board/resetCards':
      return state.map(card => ({...card, visible: false}));
    
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const wordPairs = [
  'Provider', 'Provider', 
  'selector', 'selector', 
  'useSelector()', 'useSelector()', 
  'useDispatch()', 'useDispatch()',
  'Pure Function', 'Pure Function',
  'react-redux', 'react-redux',
]

const randomWords = () => {
  let words = []
  let newWordPairs = [...wordPairs]
  const reps = newWordPairs.length
  for (let i = 0 ; i < reps ; i++) {
    const wordIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * newWordPairs.length);
    words.push(newWordPairs[wordIndex])
    newWordPairs.splice(wordIndex, 1)
  }

  return words;
} 

// action creators
export const setBoard = () => {
  const words = randomWords()
  return {
    type: 'board/setBoard',
    payload: words
  }
}

export const flipCard = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'board/flipCard',
    payload: id
  }
}

export const resetCards = (indices) => {
  return {
    type: 'board/resetCards'
  }
};
export const resetUnmatchedCards = () => {
  return {
    type: 'board/resetUnmatchedCards',
    payload: false
  }
}

// Add selector export statments below
export const selectBoard = (state) => { 
  return ( state.board.map(card=> 
  ({
    id: card.id,
    contents: card.contents
  })
  
  ))}
export const selectVisibleIDs = state => {
  return (
    state.board.filter(card => card.visible)
    .map(card => card.id)
  )
}
export const selectMatchedIDs = state => {
  return ( state.board.filter(card => card.matched)
  .map(card => card.id));
};
```

```
the App component :
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import { Score } from './features/score/Score.js';
import { Board } from './features/board/Board.js';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setBoard, resetCards } from './features/board/boardSlice';

// Add import statements below



const App = () => {
  // Add dispatch variable below
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const startGameHandler = () => {
    // Add action dispatch below
    dispatch(setBoard())
  };

  const tryAgainHandler = () => {
    // Add action dispatch below
    dispatch(resetCards())
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Score />
      <Board />
      <footer className="footer">
        <button onClick={startGameHandler} className="start-button">
          Start Game
        </button>
        <button onClick={tryAgainHandler} className="try-new-pair-button">
          Try New Pair
        </button>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
the board component :
import React from 'react';
import { CardRow } from './cardRow/CardRow.js';
// Add import statements below
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectBoard } from './boardSlice';


export const Board = () => {
  // Add selected data variable and implement below
  const currentBoard = useSelector(selectBoard);

  const numberOfCards = currentBoard.length;
  const columns = 3;
  const rows = Math.floor(numberOfCards / columns);

  const getRowCards = (row) => {
    const rowCards = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      const cardIndex = row * columns + j;
      // Implement selected data below
      rowCards.push(currentBoard[cardIndex]);
    }
    return rowCards;
  };
console.log(currentBoard)
  let content = [];
  for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    const rowCards = getRowCards(row);
    content.push(
      <CardRow 
        key={row} 
        cards={rowCards} 
      />
    );
  }
  return <div className="cards-container">{content}</div>;
};
```

```
the cardRow.js:
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from './card/Card.js';
import {selectMatchedIDs } from '../boardSlice'
export const CardRow = ({ cards }) => {
  const content = cards.map(card => 
    <Card 
      key={card.id} 
      id={card.id} 
      contents={card.contents} 
     
  />)

  return <>{content}</>;
};
```

```
the Card.js:
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
// Add import statements below

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { selectVisibleIDs, flipCard, selectMatchedIDs,  } from '../../boardSlice';
import { resetCards, resetUnmatchedCards } from '../../boardSlice'
let cardLogo = "https://static-assets.codecademy.com/Courses/Learn-Redux/matching-game/codecademy_logo.png";

export const Card = ({ id, contents }) => {
  // Add selected data and dispatch variables below
  const visibleIDs = useSelector(selectVisibleIDs) 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const matchedIDs = useSelector(selectMatchedIDs);
console.log(visibleIDs)
console.log(matchedIDs);

  // flip card action
  const flipHandler = (id) => {
    // Add action dispatch below
    dispatch(flipCard(id))
    
  };
  const resetHandler = () => {
    dispatch(resetUnmatchedCards)
  }

  let cardStyle = 'resting';
 
  let click = () => flipHandler(id);
 
  let cardText = (
    <img src={cardLogo} className="logo-placeholder" alt="Card option" />
  );

  // 1st if statement
  // implement card id array membership check
  if (visibleIDs.includes(id) || matchedIDs.includes(id)) { 
  

    cardText = contents;
    click = () => {};
  } 
  
  // 2nd if statement
  // implement card id array membership check
  if (matchedIDs.includes(id)) {
    

  cardStyle = 'matched';
  
  } else { 
 cardStyle = 'no-match';
  
  }

  // 3rd if statement
  // implement number of flipped cards check
  if (visibleIDs.length === 2) {
    if (cardStyle === 'no-match' ) {
    click = () => resetHandler(); 
    }
    click = ()=> {};
    
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={click} className={`card ${cardStyle}`}>
      {cardText}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please format your question so it's a bit more readable. Entire paragraph is one sentence, I can't really figure out what you're asking. Also please try to include only code relevant to the problem you're having.

Comment: ok my friend you are right

Answer (score -1):

so the problem is i want to change the click button to an other function to do so when first every card had this object {id:cardId, contents: cardContents, visible: false, matched: false} so first of when the user click two cards by the "FlipCard" action the card.visible become true then if the first card.contents is ht same as the second card.contents so the card.matched property for the two cards will become true so the require thing I want to add another function to reset the two card.visible to false when the first card.contents is not the same as the second card.contents so this is my code of the component Card :

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
// Add import statements below

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { selectVisibleIDs, flipCard, selectMatchedIDs,  } from '../../boardSlice';
import { resetCards, resetUnmatchedCards } from '../../boardSlice'
let cardLogo = "https://static-assets.codecademy.com/Courses/Learn-Redux/matching-game/codecademy_logo.png";

export const Card = ({ id, contents }) => {
  // Add selected data and dispatch variables below
  const visibleIDs = useSelector(selectVisibleIDs) 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const matchedIDs = useSelector(selectMatchedIDs);

console.log(matchedIDs);

  // flip card action
  const flipHandler = (id) => {
    // Add action dispatch below
    dispatch(flipCard(id))
    
  };
  const resetHandler = () => {
    dispatch(resetCards)
  }

  let cardStyle = 'resting';
 
  let click = () => flipHandler(id);
 
  let cardText = (
    <img src={cardLogo} className="logo-placeholder" alt="Card option" />
  );

  // 1st if statement
  // implement card id array membership check
  if (visibleIDs.includes(id) || matchedIDs.includes(id)) { 
  

    cardText = contents;
    click = () => {};
  } 
  
  // 2nd if statement
  // implement card id array membership check
  if (matchedIDs.includes(id)) {
    

  cardStyle = 'matched';
  
  } else { 
 cardStyle = 'no-match';
  
  }
console.log(visibleIDs.every(id => matchedIDs.includes(id)))
  // 3rd if statement
  // implement number of flipped cards check
  if (visibleIDs.length === 2 ) {
  if (cardStyle === 'no-match'  && visibleIDs.every(id => !matchedIDs.includes(id))) {
    
    click = () => resetHandler(); 
    } else {
    
    click = () => {};
    }
 
    }

  return (
    <button onClick={click} className={`card ${cardStyle}`}>
      {cardText}
    </button>
  );
};
```